# Mapping categorical data from user input to its actual encoded value for prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, categorical-data, label-encoding

A portion of my dataset looks like this (there are many other processor types in my actual data)

```
df.head(4)
 Processor Task Difficulty Time
  i3        34    3         6
  i7        34    3         4
  i3        50    1         6
  i5        25    2         5
```

I have created a regression model to predict `Time` when `Type, Task` are `Difficulty` are given as inputs.

I have done `label encoding` first to change `Processor` which is categorical.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df['Processor'] = le.fit_transform(df['Processor'])


df.head(4)
 Processor Task Difficulty Time
  12        34    3         6
  8         34    3         4
  12        50    1         6
  2         25    2         5
```

This is my regression model

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1)
rf_model.fit(features,target)
```

I want to predict `Time` for the input `"i5", 20, 1`.

How can I do label encoding to `"i5"` to map it to get the same value as in my encoded dataframe in which `i5` is encoded to `2`?

I tried this

```
rf_model.predict([[le.fit_transform('i5'),20,1]])
```

However I got an output prediction different from the actual value when i5 is entered as 2,

```
rf_model.predict([[2,20,1)]])
```

Comment: why you are using LabelEncoder instead of OneHotEncoder or LableBinarizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are using `fit_transform`. This reassigns the categories instead of using the existing encoding, so if you do `le.transform` it should work. For example, something like your data:

```
np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Processor':np.random.choice(['i3','i5','i7'],50),
                  'Task':np.random.randint(25,50,50),
                  'Difficulty':np.random.randint(1,4,50),
                  'Time':np.random.randint(1,7,50)})
```

We make the target and feature, then fit :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
features = df.iloc[:,:3]
features['Processor'] = le.fit_transform(features['Processor'])
target = df['Time']

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1)
rf_model.fit(features,target)
```

'i5' would be 1:

```
le.classes_
array(['i3', 'i5', 'i7'], dtype=object)
```

Check predictions:

```
rf_model.predict([[le.transform(['i5']),20,1]])

array([3.975])
```

And:

```
rf_model.predict([[1,20,1]])

array([3.975])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
print(le.fit_transform(['i5']))
# [2]
```

Comment: I don't know why this is not working for me, I tried print(le.fit_transform(['i5'])) and print(le.fit_transform(['i7'])) both gave me the same output viz. # [0]

Comment: check your label classes `le.classes_ ` it Holds the label for each class.